# How to add Authorization header in getTileUrl for ImageMapType Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, http-headers

I would like to access some Custom Map Tiles hosted on the different host who need a user / pass, when creating a TileOverlay for Google Maps API.

So this is my current code Javascript:

```
var carte = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function (tileCoord, zoom) {
        var url = "http://host.com/" + (zoom + 1) + "/" + (tileCoord.x + 1) + ":" + (tileCoord.y + 1) + "/tile.png";
        return url;
    }, 
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256), 
    minZoom: 8, 
    opacity: 0.6
});
map.overlayMapTypes.push(carte);
```

Since the connection returns 401 Anauthorized, I can't access the tiles. How could I pass Authorization header in Javascript/Jquery to let the url know I am authorized to access those tiles?

I'm searching a solution like this, but in Javascript : [Adding an Authorization header in getTileUrl for Maps Tile Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739880/adding-an-authorization-header-in-gettileurl-for-maps-tile-android)

Comment: Are you searching for this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=en

Comment: I'm searching a solution like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739880/adding-an-authorization-header-in-gettileurl-for-maps-tile-android, but in Javascript.

Comment: @Ulyanca , did you found a solution for this? I'm dealing with the exact same issue and i hoped you can point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution by impementing the proxy.
Here is the code implemeted :

```
var carte = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tileCoord, zoom) {
            return 'http://myhost/myController/getTile?url=http://externe_url/' + (zoom + 1) + "/" + (tileCoord.x + 1) + ":" + (tileCoord.y + 1) + "/tile.png";
        }, 
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),  
        minZoom: 8,  
        opacity: 0.6
    });
```

Code of my controller :

```
def getTile() {
def result
try {
    def http = new HTTPBuilder()
    try {
        http.setHeaders([Authorization: 'Basic ' + 'user:pass'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()])
        http.request(params.url, Method.GET, ContentType.BINARY) { req ->
            response.success = { resp, retour ->
                result = retour.bytes
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) { }
}

if(result) {
    // on renvoie au navigateur le contenu de l'image
    response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    response.contentType = 'image/x-png'
    response.outputStream << result
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
else {
    response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the user agent wants to send the server authentication credentials it may use the Authorization field.

The Authorization field is constructed as follows:

The username and password are combined with a single colon.
The resulting string is encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line.
The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.

Source : [Http Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

```
$.ajax({
        type: // POST OR GET,
        url: //your url,
        headers: {
            Authorization:"Basic "+new Buffer(name+':'+pass).toString('base64'),
            "Content-Type" : //according to you
        }
        })
       .done(function(data) { });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: he asked how to pass authorization header in javascript/jquery , thats how its passed.

Comment: Even if the code posted does answer the question, a good answer will help explain **why** the code solves the problem.  Code-only answers are considered to be low-quality on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but this is not really my problème. I search a solution like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739880/adding-an-authorization-header-in-gettileurl-for-maps-tile-android, but in Javascript.